# Facebook API - access token works for SOME requests

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

This is driving me totally crazy. I've set up an FB app and retrieved an access token by visiting: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET.

Now I want to grab a (publicly available) feed from this URL: https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_OR_USER_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

It works fine when I try it with my own user ID or even when I try another random page but it DOESN'T work when I enter the PAGE_ID I need it to work with.

Here are some examples:

This works fine (a friend of mine's Facebook page):
https://graph.facebook.com/tatchit/feed?access_token=213451182120494|JgAwuCE74lh51t1pKMuRM2mz3GU&limit=10&offset=0

This also works fine (my own Facebook ID):
https://graph.facebook.com/al.dev.7/feed?access_token=213451182120494|JgAwuCE74lh51t1pKMuRM2mz3GU&limit=10&offset=0

This doesn't work (the client's Facebook page):
https://graph.facebook.com/142616539131188/feed?access_token=213451182120494|JgAwuCE74lh51t1pKMuRM2mz3GU&limit=10&offset=0

I don't get any errors but the result is empty.

If I try the Graph API Explorer it also works fine:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=142616539131188%2Ffeed

But not if I enter my own access token. From what I understand the access tokens you get in the API Explorer are temporary so I don't want to use that.

How can this be?

Also. I've struggled to understand this whole access-token, client-id, app-id-business for ages now - is there a good tutorial where all this stuff is explained? I've never had this work without problems ever.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using user access token for all the above queries. App Access token is used when you want to do something like check the app insights so and so.

When the pages has age restrictions or something so, app token wont be able to get through, but since the user is already a member of the page, you can use the user access token to get the data.

Add : Quoting from the documentation,

```
Note that the **app access token** is for publishing purposes permitted by the publish_actions and publish_stream permissions. You will be **unable to retrieve information** about the status update post with the given ID using the app access token. Instead, you should use a **user access token** for such purposes.
```

**Other Capabilities of an App Access Token**
There is a limited set of information that can be retrieved from Facebook using an App Access Token.

```
    Basic Profile Info of a User (ID, Name, Username, Gender)
    A User’s Friends and their IDs
    Permissions granted by the User to your App
```

Read : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/

So you should be querying with the user_access token to access all the informations that you are looking for, not with an app access_token.

Comment: Are you saying that in order for me to display a Facebook Page's feed on my website the user visiting my website needs to log in to Facebook through my website ("Log in with Facebook") so that I can pass that information to Facebook? Is there no way to display a Facebook feed _without_ having the user log in? (As is possible with the first two examples I provided)

Comment: Depends on the type of page as far as  I know. Some pages has age restrictions, and app access_tokens cant get into those pages. (Pages which are marked  - contains alchohol, which are age restricted)

You would need the user to login manually when he needs to add you app. Why not get the user access token then? (Extended expiry or normal ones). Use user_access token to retrieve, app_access token should be used only to post.(Thats what FB wants us to do. Doesnt mean app access_token cant retrieve, but it is limited.) I updated my answer. Check it.

Comment: Ok thanks. The thing is that I don't require my visitors to "Sign in with Facebook" at all. All I use the App for is to get an access token to fetch my feed. But the page I'm trying to fetch from is actually an alcohol-related one with an age restriction so I guess that's why then.

Comment: You can get a 60 day expiry user access_token the time user adds your application. You can then determine whether you want to or not want to show the signin button by checking its expiry. Checkout : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/ and  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/debugging-access-tokens/

Answer (score 1):

You are using an App Access token instead of a User Access token. Some of the pages you are viewing may have a country or age restriction set, so using an app token will not work.

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/

Comment: I gave you a +1 but gave the correct answer to Kishor. You are both right however.